# How to get the submit button appear down the page

Tags: html, css

i am working on this student profile project. it is in the designing phases. The problem i am facing is that the submit button isn't appearing at the bottom of the page. Rather it is appearing right in the first section of the page. can you please help me with it?
Best regards,

```css
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container{
 width:700px;
 margin:0 auto;
 
}
label{
 display:block;
}

.header{
 
 background: #2196F3;
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border-width: 1px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 1px auto;
 padding: 10px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center
 }
.under_header{
 font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 
}
.segment_header {
 text-align:Left;
    width: auto;
    margin: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #2196F3 none repeat scroll 50% 50% / cover;
    border-radius: 4px;
 font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:18px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.question{
 padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.question .top_question{
 display: block !important;
 min-height: 19px;
}
.question .text_field{
 background: #FAFAFA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
 display:block;
}
.question .drop_down {
    background: #FAFAFA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px 0px;
    padding: 9px;
 display:block;
}
.question .item_anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}

.full_width {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
}
.required .icon{
 background-image: none;
 background-position: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding-left: 14px;
}
.question .matrix {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.form_table{
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 0px solid #CCCCCC;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 background-size: cover;
 color: #333333;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}
.form_table table {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.question .matrix th{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: #64B5F6;
 padding: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.question .matrix td{
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 height: 26px;
 
}

.question .matrix td.question{
 
 font-weight: normal;
}

.question .matrix .multi_scale_sub th{
 font-weight: normal;
 border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
 background: #999999;
}

.question .matrix .multi_scale_break{
 border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.question .matrix_row_dark td{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FAFAFA;
}

.question .matrix_row_dark td.question{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FAFAFA;
}

.question .matrix_row_light td{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

.question .matrix_row_light td.question{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

.question .rating_ranking td{
 padding: 5px;
}

.question .scroller{
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.highlight{
 background: #FFF9C4 !important;
}

tr.highlight td{
 background: #FFF9C4 !important;
}

.outside{
 color: #333333;
}

.outside_container{
 
 width: 650px;
 padding: 1em 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 color: #333333;
}
.submit_button {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 1px;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-out 0s;
    white-space: normal;
}

.outside_container .submit_button{
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
 background: #FF9800;
 background-size: auto;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 min-width: 30%;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}
.buttons_reverse {
     direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
}
.outside_container .submit_button:hover{
 background: #F57C00;
 border-color: #BBBBBB;
 background-size: auto;
}
.progressBarWrapper{
 border-radius: 4px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 background-size: cover;
 border-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.progressBarBack{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #FF9800;
}
.progressBarFront{
 color: #333333;
}

.ui-widget{
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}
.invalid{
 background: #FFEEEE;
}
.invalid .invalid_message{
 color: #FF0000;
 background: #FFEEEE;
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.form_table.invalid{
 border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
.invalid .matrix .invalid_row{
 background: #FFEEEE;
}
```

```html
<form id="FSform" method="post" style="">
<div id="q23" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor3"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-3">First Name</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-3" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-3" size="22" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div id="q24" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor4"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-4">Last Name</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-4" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-4" size="22" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div id="q49" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor5"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-5">Class</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-5" name="RESULT_RadioButton-5" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">AS Level</option>
<option value="Radio-1">A Level</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q21" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor6"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-5">Gender</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-5" name="RESULT_RadioButton-5" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">Male</option>
<option value="Radio-1">Female</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q12" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor7"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-7">Group</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-7" name="RESULT_RadioButton-7" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">Engineering</option>
<option value="Radio-1">Medical</option>
<option value="Radio-2">General</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q25" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor8"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-8">Street Address</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-8" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-8" size="52" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div id="q27" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor9"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-9">City</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-9" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-9" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div id="q28" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor10"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-10">Province/State</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-10" name="RESULT_RadioButton-10" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">Punjab</option>
<option value="Radio-1">KPK</option>
<option value="Radio-2">Sindh</option>
<option value="Radio-3">Baluchistan</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q30" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor11"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-11">Phone Number</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-11" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-11" size="34" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div id="q31" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor12"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-12">Email Address</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-12" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-12" size="52" maxlength="255" value="" type="email">
</div>




<div class="outside_container">
<div class="buttons_reverse"><input name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submit_button" id="FSsubmit" type="submit"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `css` for `outside_container` class, add following

```
clear : both;
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Now define your

```
.outside_container{  clear:both;}
```

as like this

Answer (score 0):

```css
input[type="button"], input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"], button {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container{
 width:700px;
 margin:0 auto;
 
}
label{
 display:block;
}

.header{
 
 background: #2196F3;
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 2px;
 border-width: 1px;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
 margin: 1px auto;
 padding: 10px;
 display:block;
 text-align:center
 }
.under_header{
 font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
 padding:10px;
 font-size: 15px;
 
}
.segment_header {
 text-align:Left;
    width: auto;
    margin: 1px;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #2196F3 none repeat scroll 50% 50% / cover;
    border-radius: 4px;
 font-family:Roboto,sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:18px;
 padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
.question{
 padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.question .top_question{
 display: block !important;
 min-height: 19px;
}
.question .text_field{
 background: #FAFAFA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
 display:block;
}
.question .drop_down {
    background: #FAFAFA none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: "Roboto",sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 1px 0px;
    padding: 9px;
 display:block;
}
.question .item_anchor {
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
}

.full_width {
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 0px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100%;
}
.required .icon{
 background-image: none;
 background-position: left;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding-left: 14px;
}
.question .matrix {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-right: 3px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
.form_table{
 width: 650px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 0px solid #CCCCCC;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 background-size: cover;
 color: #333333;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}
.form_table table {
    font-size: 1em;
}
.question .matrix th{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background: #64B5F6;
 padding: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align: bottom;
}

.question .matrix td{
 padding: 5px;
 text-align: center;
 white-space: nowrap;
 height: 26px;
 
}

.question .matrix td.question{
 
 font-weight: normal;
}

.question .matrix .multi_scale_sub th{
 font-weight: normal;
 border-top: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
 background: #999999;
}

.question .matrix .multi_scale_break{
 border-right: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.question .matrix_row_dark td{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FAFAFA;
}

.question .matrix_row_dark td.question{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FAFAFA;
}

.question .matrix_row_light td{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

.question .matrix_row_light td.question{
 color: #333333;
 background: #FFFFFF;
}

.question .rating_ranking td{
 padding: 5px;
}

.question .scroller{
 border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.highlight{
 background: #FFF9C4 !important;
}

tr.highlight td{
 background: #FFF9C4 !important;
}

.outside{
 color: #333333;
}

.outside_container{
 
 width: 650px;
 padding: 1em 0;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 text-align: center;
 color: #333333;
}
.submit_button {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 1px;
    transition: background 0.1s ease-out 0s;
    white-space: normal;
}

.outside_container .submit_button{
 color: #FFFFFF !important;
 background: #FF9800;
 background-size: auto;
 border-style: none;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 min-width: 30%;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.30);
}
.buttons_reverse {
     direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
}
.outside_container .submit_button:hover{
 background: #F57C00;
 border-color: #BBBBBB;
 background-size: auto;
}
.progressBarWrapper{
 border-radius: 4px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 background-size: cover;
 border-color: #CCCCCC;
}
.progressBarBack{
 color: #FFFFFF;
 background-color: #FF9800;
}
.progressBarFront{
 color: #333333;
}

.ui-widget{
 font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
}
.invalid{
 background: #FFEEEE;
}
.invalid .invalid_message{
 color: #FF0000;
 background: #FFEEEE;
 border: 1px solid #FF0000;
 border-radius: 2px;
}
.form_table.invalid{
 border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
.invalid .matrix .invalid_row{
 background: #FFEEEE;
}
.form-wrapper{
  display: table;
 }
```

```html
<form id="FSform" method="post" style="">

<div class="form-wrapper">
<div id="q23" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor3"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-3">First Name</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-3" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-3" size="22" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div id="q24" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor4"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-4">Last Name</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-4" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-4" size="22" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>
<div id="q49" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor5"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-5">Class</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-5" name="RESULT_RadioButton-5" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">AS Level</option>
<option value="Radio-1">A Level</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q21" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor6"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-5">Gender</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-5" name="RESULT_RadioButton-5" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">Male</option>
<option value="Radio-1">Female</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q12" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor7"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-7">Group</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-7" name="RESULT_RadioButton-7" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">Engineering</option>
<option value="Radio-1">Medical</option>
<option value="Radio-2">General</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q25" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor8"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-8">Street Address</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-8" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-8" size="52" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div id="q27" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor9"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-9">City</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-9" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-9" size="30" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div id="q28" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor10"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_RadioButton-10">Province/State</label>
<select id="RESULT_RadioButton-10" name="RESULT_RadioButton-10" class="drop_down">
<option></option>
<option value="Radio-0">Punjab</option>
<option value="Radio-1">KPK</option>
<option value="Radio-2">Sindh</option>
<option value="Radio-3">Baluchistan</option>
</select>
</div>

<div id="q30" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor11"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-11">Phone Number</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-11" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-11" size="34" maxlength="255" value="" type="text">
</div>

<div id="q31" class="question">
<a class="item_anchor" name="ItemAnchor12"></a>
<label class="question top_question" for="RESULT_TextField-12">Email Address</label>
<input name="RESULT_TextField-12" class="text_field" id="RESULT_TextField-12" size="52" maxlength="255" value="" type="email">
</div>

</div>


<div class="outside_container">
<div class="buttons_reverse"><input name="Submit" value="Submit" class="submit_button" id="FSsubmit" type="submit"></div></div>
```

Comment: This can be achieved in many ways. I just wrapped the form contents except the submit button in a div.